# Wrapping WordPress Latest Post Link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to wrap a div with a link to the latest post. Currently, the code returns the value of the featured image to use as the background image for a continuing div. I just want to wrap it with the url for the latest post. Thanks

```html
<?php
/* Get Recent Post */
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
/* If Featured Image Set */
if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent_post[0]['ID']) ){
    /* Get Image */
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent_post[0]['ID']), 'full');
    /* Output Div with Image Set Inline, Use padding Top for Responsive Ratio Size */
    echo '
<div class="featured-image-div" style="background-image:url('.$image[0].');"></div>
    ';                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_permalink` like so

```php
/* If Featured Image Set */
if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent_post[0]['ID']) ){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($recent_post[0]['ID']), 'full');
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink($recent_post[0]['ID']) . '">
<div class="featured-image-div" style="background-image:url('.$image[0].');"></div></a>
    ';                           
}
```

Function documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/

Comment: Hey Josh, this did not work for me. I'm using a PHP plugin so that I can use it as a widget. The image is missing when I tried this.

Comment: Did the image work in the first place? The bit I added shouldn't effect the image at all.

Comment: Yes it did. But it wasn't linked :(

Comment: And your image works again when you remove get_the_permalink?

Comment: Yep. I just reverted back to the original code and the image appears but not linked.